# How to combine two half datasets?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two datasets; genuine account and fake account. I want to create a new dataset where I combine 50% of genuine accounts and 50% of fake accounts. I have seen method like .join() from pandas but I don't know how to only take half of the dataset for the combination. For now, I only import two of the datasets and I don't know what to do next.

```
dataset_genuine = pd.read_csv('users_genuine.csv')
dataset_fake = pd.read_csv('users_fake.csv')
```

Comment: `pd.concat` probably

Answer (score 0):

This is probably how you would want to do something like this

```
dataset_genuine = pd.read_csv('users_genuine.csv').sample(frac = 0.5)
dataset_fake = pd.read_csv('users_fake.csv').sample(frac = 0.5)
pd.concat([dataset_genuine, dataset_fake])
```

Your question really needs more details to ensure this is exactly what you are looking for, but based on what I could infer this should allow you to take a sample of 50% from each csv and combine them together

Comment: Just a side note. If a random sample isn't required but a 1 in N will do, then you can provide `skiprows=lambda index: index % 2` as an argument to `pd.read_csv`.

Comment: Or maybe `skiprows=lambda v: random.choice([False, True])` but that's not going to be 50%

Comment: Does my way not randomize it, just pulls back the first 50%?

Comment: `frac` does a random sample

Comment: Ok I thought so, so what was the problem with my code, or were you just give some other techniques to use?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code... just throwing another idea into the mix

Comment: Oh nice ok cool haha, I was like I could have sworn this is what they needed! Thanks for the additional choices to help give more options later =)